# ofstream returns a random variable c++

Tags: c++

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my function of matrix multiplication?

```
ofstream multiplication(ifstream& lhs, ifstream& rhs) {
    int rows_lhs = 0, cols_lhs = 0;
    int rows_rhs = 0, cols_rhs = 0;
    if (!lhs.eof() && !rhs.eof()) {
        lhs >> rows_lhs >> cols_lhs;
        rhs >> rows_rhs >> cols_rhs;
    }
    float matrix_lhs[rows_lhs][cols_lhs];
    float matrix_rhs[rows_rhs][cols_rhs];
    float el = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_lhs; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols_lhs; ++j) {
            lhs >> el;
            matrix_lhs[i][j] = el;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_rhs; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols_rhs; ++j) {
            rhs >> el;
            matrix_rhs[i][j] = el;
        }
    }
    float matrix_res[rows_lhs][cols_rhs];
    float left_el = 0.0;
    float right_el = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_lhs; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols_rhs; ++j) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < cols_lhs; ++k) {
                left_el = matrix_lhs[i][k];
                right_el = matrix_rhs[k][j];
                matrix_res[i][j] += left_el * right_el;
            }
        }
    }
    ofstream out;
    out.open("output.txt");
    out << rows_lhs << ' ' << cols_rhs << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_lhs; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols_rhs; ++j) {
            out << matrix_res[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        out << '\n';
    }
    out.close();
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream infile_1("1.txt");
    ifstream infile_2("3.txt");
    ofstream out = multiplication(infile_1, infile_2);
    float res = 0;
    while (!out.eof()) {
        out << res;
    }
}
```

I have two files: 1.txt with values

```
1 3
1 2 3
```

and 2.txt with values

```
3 1
4 5 6
```

When I run function above I expected to see:

```
1 1
32
```

but I got:

```
1 1
-3.424e+26
```

I can't undestand why multiplication value is wrong?

I tried to solve problem by CLion debugger, but debugger showed correct value 32 and it surprised me.

Comment: `float matrix_lhs[rows_lhs][cols_lhs];` defines a set of variable-length arrays. [C++ doesn't have such arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: What's the purpose of returning a closed `ofstream` by value?

Comment: Also please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Oh, and streams can't be copied. How does the function even build when you return a stream by value?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `matrix_res` before summing into it.  So it could contain anything.  Hint:  Set all entries to `0` before trying to sum into it.

Comment: And `while (!out.eof())`? That doesn't even make any sense. What are you doing with all your streams? What is the output stream to be used for? When inside that loop will `res` ever change value? How do you write to stream that is closed?

Comment: Your program appears to open the file `3.txt` instad of `2.txt`.  What is in the file `3.txt`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude rvo? Compiles without errors: https://godbolt.org/z/KT9GvW4oT

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Also for running your own tests yuo should seperate reading input from a file and the actual calculations so that you can test as much as possible with hardcoded input. When your code relies on external files, others cannot run your code without those files

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Probably. Which means there's probably a defect somewhere if that's allowed. Someone with some clout in the standards comity should probably take a closer look at a case like that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude anyhow, even if it is possible and does the right thing, I'd argue that here in this code its the wrong approach to return an `ostream` from the function

Comment: BTW, execution continues after the `if` statement if both streams are set to `eof`.  Did you want the execution to continue when both streams are in `eof` state?

Comment: Variable Length Arrays, ex. `float m[rows][columns]`, are not part of the standard C++ language.  Either use `std::vector` or dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: Why is `out << res` inside a `while` loop?  The `res` variable doesn't change within the loop.  Also, think about `eof` with an output file.  This is either a constant condition (the file position is always at the end, and each character is appended) or it could mean that you have run out of file space.  Can you think of other test cases where an output file stream sets the `eof` state?

Comment: @nameisnoname To summarize: You seem to have some pretty misunderstandings about C++ and its streams. Take a few steps back, and if you're serious about learning C++ then invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn properly.